# How to read EACF in R?

Tags: r, time-series, arima, model-selection

[image]

This is my eacf plot but I don't know how to read and interpretate it. I wanna know what AR and MA I possibly got from this. Please help me, thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What does EACF stand for? How have you obtained it?